What are these weird highlights occurring randomly on spyder-python
Every time I click on this or make any changes, weird highlights are created, occurring more so while I minimise a function. Any suggestion how to get rid of these or as to what could be the reason for such? Thanks!
I have tried to change settings in the appearance preferences and have not been able to affect the problem whatsoever.


Disable bracket pair colorization by going file > preferences > settings and disable code folding highlight by going settings and search for Editor > Code Lens. This should fix it.  Also, keep in mind that this is a non-programming issue in here, so consider next time to use better tags or other forums. Hope it works.

Hello, do you want to turn off parentheses and code highlighting in your code? You can try searching for editor.matchBrackets in the settings again and setting it to never. Turn off active line highlighting by setting editor.lineHighlight to none. Turn off all the same variable or symbol instances by setting editor.linkedEditing to false.

@dann keep in mind that this is a non-programming issue in here so consider next time to use better tags or other forums. I don't see an issue here, have you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic which specifically mentions software tools commonly used by programmers;?
